# Remove Widgets in Dashboard

Tags: plugins, widgets, dashboard

Another noob question...when authors log on and access their Dashboard, they see all sorts of widgets such as an Internet Explorer warning, news on what's going on with WordPress.

Is there anyway to remove all of these for all users (present and future), so that they only see the 'Quick Press' & 'Right Now' widgets?

Thanks!

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced:_Removing_Dashboard_Widgets

Comment: Thanks I just tried it now..but it didnt remove the widgets...                                                 // Create the function to use in the action hook

function example_remove_dashboard_widgets() {
 remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side' );
 remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_incoming_links', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
} 

// Hoook into the 'wp_dashboard_setup' action to register our function

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_remove_dashboard_widgets' );

Comment: Please paste the code you tried and more details on how you're using it in your answer, please.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to go about this is to create a new plugin (or put in the theme function.php but a plugin will always work independent of theme) that disables the widgets you don't need. Something like this.

```
function wpse_47707_disable_admin_meta() {
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_browser_nag', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal' );

}

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_47707_disable_admin_meta' );
```

See [The Codex Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced%3a_Removing_Dashboard_Widgets) for more info on meta boxes