# Replace dashboard widgets with banner ad

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I know it's probably not encouraged, but is there a way to replace the standard dashboard widgets (Recent Drafts, Quickpress, etc.) with a standard image banner ad?

I know how to add new dashboard widgets, but I want this to be a plain image with no surrounding widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this reference

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-dashboard-widgets-in-wordpress/

for adding dashboard widget

[Remove Widgets in Dashboard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47707/remove-widgets-in-dashboard)

for removing dashboard widget

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_remove_dashboard_widgets' );
function example_remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_drafts', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_secondary', 'dashboard', 'side' );

    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_browser_nag', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_incoming_links', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_plugins', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Theme Support', 'custom_dashboard_help');
}
function custom_dashboard_help() {
    echo 'Your custom banner code';
    }
```

Comment: Please provide code in answers, not just links - there is no guarantee that those resources will always be available. :)

Comment: check my edit..

Answer (score 3):

```
// Add & Remove meta boxes
function wpse50413_alter_dashboard_widgets()
{
    // For details on removing widgets, see answer by @janw
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_plugins', 'dashboard', 'normal' );

    // @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
    add_meta_box( 'dashboard_ad_widget', 'Your Ad Title here', 'wpse50413_add_adbox', null, 'dashboard' );
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse50413_alter_dashboard_widgets' );

// The callback function, that defines the ad
function wpse50413_add_adbox()
{
    // display add here - this is the ad boxes contents
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is here: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Examples

remove all standard dashboard widgets:
in functions.php

```
<?php
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_remove_dashboard_widgets' );
function example_remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_drafts', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_secondary', 'dashboard', 'side' );

    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_browser_nag', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_incoming_links', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_plugins', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
}
```